# Apagar dados clicar no botão voltar

Tags: android, kotlin

Criei uma calculadora IMC no qual possui duas telas:

- a Tela 1 voce inclui peso e altura
- a Tela 2 aparece o resultado do calculo onde na tela resultado possui um botão de voltar.

Gostaria de saber qual o Código que eu posso usar para quando o usuário clicar no botão voltar os dados da primeira tela estejam apagados.

Segue abaixo os Código das duas telas:

Tela 1

```
package com.example.calculadoraimc
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val btnCalcular: Button = findViewById(R.id.btnCalcular)
        val edtPeso: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_peso)
        val edtAltura: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_altura)




        btnCalcular.setOnClickListener {

            val alturaStr = edtAltura.text.toString()
            val pesoStr = edtPeso.text.toString()

            if(alturaStr.isNotEmpty() && pesoStr.isNotEmpty()) {


                val altura: Float = alturaStr.toFloat()
                val alturaFinal: Float = altura * altura
                val peso: Float = pesoStr.toFloat()
                val result: Float = peso / alturaFinal


//Essa intent vai me levar dessa tela para a ResultActivity

                val intent = Intent(this, ResultActivity::class.java)
                    .apply {

                        putExtra("EXTRA_RESULT", result)

                    }

                //Aqui eu inicializo minha intent
                startActivity(intent)

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Preencher todos campos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }


      }

    }
```

Tela 2 onde imprime o resultado e possui o botão voltar:

```
package com.example.calculadoraimc

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView


@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
class ResultActivity :AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result)

        supportActionBar?.setHomeButtonEnabled(true)
        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)


        val tvResult = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_result)
        val tvClassificacao = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview_classificacao)

        val result = intent.getFloatExtra("EXTRA_RESULT", 0.1f)

        tvResult.text = result.toString()

        /*TABELA IMC
    MENOR QUE 18,5       ABAIXO DO PESO 0
    ENTRE 18,5 E 24,9    NORMAL 0
    ENTRE 25,0 E 29,9    SOBREPESO I
    ENTRE 30,0 E 39,9    OBESIDADE II
    MAIOR QUE  40,0      OBESIDADE GRAVE III
    */
                var classificao = ""

                if (result < 18.5f) {

        classificao = "ABAIXO DO PESO"
        tvClassificacao.setTextColor ( resources.getColor(R.color.blue_200))
        tvResult.setTextColor ( resources.getColor(R.color.blue_200))

        } else if (result >= 18.5f && result <= 24.9f) {

        classificao = "NORMAL"
        tvClassificacao.setTextColor( resources.getColor(R.color.green))
        tvResult.setTextColor ( resources.getColor(R.color.green))

        } else if (result >= 25f && result <= 29.9f) {

        classificao = "SOBREPESO"
        tvClassificacao.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.yellow))
        tvResult.setTextColor ( resources.getColor(R.color.yellow))

        } else if (result >= 30f && result <= 39.9f) {

        classificao = "OBESIDADE"
        tvClassificacao.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.orange))
        tvResult.setTextColor ( resources.getColor(R.color.orange))

        } else{

        classificao = "OBESIDADE MÓRBIDA"
        tvClassificacao.setTextColor(resources.getColor(R.color.red))
        tvResult.setTextColor ( resources.getColor(R.color.red))
        }


        tvClassificacao.text = getString(R.string.message_classificacao, classificao)

        }

        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

                finish()

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)

        }


}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Olá,
Você pode utilizar activity for result:

```
fun startActivityResult() =
        registerForActivityResult(
            ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
        ) { result ->
            if (result.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // limpe os dados dos campos aqui

        }
}
```

Como utilizar:

Ao inves de:

```
//Aqui eu inicializo minha intent
startActivity(intent)
```

Chame:

```
val result = startActivityResult()
result.launch(intent)
```

Na segunda tela adicione o seguinte código:

```
private val onBackPressedCallback: OnBackPressedCallback =
    object : OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            finish()
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)
        }
    }
```

Use-o dentro do oncreate logo após o setContentView

```
 onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(onBackPressedCallback)
```

Em todo local que você chamar finish() vc deve adicionar em seguida setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)

**O que cada parte do código está fazendo:**

**registerForActivityResult** permite que uma tela "ouça" o resultado da tela seguinte, desse modo quando a tela 2 for fechada você poderá realizar uma ação como limpar os campos que você precisa.
**setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)** Com essa linha você está dizendo para a tela1 que está "ouvindo" a tela2 que a tela2 terminou de acordo com o esperado.

**onBackPressedCallback**
Essa é a forma como controlamos atualmente no android o botão de voltar de uma tela, então ao ser realizado uma ação de voltar você poderá definir o resultado como Ok chamando **setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK)**

Documentação caso necessário: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=pt-br

Answer (score -2):

Dentro da função de calculo de IMC, depois de calcular e inserir o resultado da operação dentro de uma variável, insira novos valores para os campos de onde você está pegando os valores usados operação. Geralmente inserir o valor como "" já resolve.

Answer (score -2):

Para limpar os campos da tela 1 quando o usuário voltar da tela 2, você pode adicionar um código na função `onResume()` da MainActivity para resetar os campos.

Você pode adicionar o seguinte código na MainActivity:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    val edtPeso: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_peso)
    val edtAltura: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext_altura)

    edtPeso.setText("")
    edtAltura.setText("")
}
```

Este código limpa o conteúdo dos campos de texto `edittext_peso` e `edittext_altura` sempre que a MainActivity é retomada.

Além disso, para que o botão de voltar na ActionBar da tela 2 chame a função `onResume()` da MainActivity, você precisa sobrescrever o método `onOptionsItemSelected()` na tela 2 e verificar se o item selecionado é o botão de voltar (android.R.id.home). Se for, você pode finalizar a tela atual e voltar para a MainActivity:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            finish()
            return true
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

Adicione este código na tela 2, dentro da classe `ResultActivity`.

Comment: A que bom deu certo!! Gratidão pela partilha do seu conhecimento